# SQL Outer Join Time Replace Null Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timestamp, outer-join

(SQL SERVER 2008)
I have timestamped records in multiple tables to join to a master/base table.  The timepoints are sometimes equal to the base table, but sometimes not.

Code to create tables:

```
create table base (time float);
create table table2 (time float, val2 char(1));
create table table3 (time float, val3 int);
insert into base values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
insert into table2 values (1, 'a'),(5, 'z'),(6, 'm'),(9, 'b');
insert into table3 values (1.5, 1),(5.3, 10),(5.5, 0),(8.1, 4);
```

The result set should be one row per record from the base table and the "most recent" value from the other tables.  Previously, these tables were "joined" in Excel using Vlookup set to TRUE, which takes the closest-without-going-over match from a sorted table.

Final result should look like:

```
time | val2 | val3
1  | a | NULL
2  | a | 1
3  | a | 1
4  | a | 1
5  | z | 1
6  | m | 0
7  | m | 0
8  | m | 0
9  | b | 4
10 | b | 4
```

How can I replicate this with a SQL statement?

I'll take readability over efficiency here since there are only ~100 records at play.

Comment: How time 1.5 from `table3` related with times from `base`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the most readable are correlated subqueries in the `select` clause:

I'm not generally a fan of `select` within `select`, but the correlated subquery does mimic the behavior of the Excel vlookup.

```
Select
  b.time,
  (Select max(t2.val2) From table2 t2 Where b.time >= t2.time) As val2,
  (Select max(t3.val3) From table3 t3 Where b.time >= t3.time) As val3
From
  base b
Order By
  b.time;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3545e/18

(Thank you Laurence for the above code and the SQL Fiddle.)

The use of `max` requires that the values be non-decreasing.  The following version works regardless:

```
select
  b.time,
  (select top 1 t2.val2 from table2 t2 where b.time >= t2.time order by t2.time Desc) as val2,
  (select top 1 t3.val3 from table3 t3 where b.time >= t3.time order by t3.time Desc) as val3
from
  base b
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5148/5

Comment: @Laurence . . . Thank you very much.  I've been trying to put that code into the answer for the past 5 minutes.

Comment: No worries, much neater and extends to more tables in a more straightforward way than mine.

Comment: The correct version, though is `select top 1 t2.val . . . order by time desc`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  almost, got it with this: `select b.time,
       (select top 1 t2.val2 from table2 t2 where b.time >= t2.time order by t2.time desc) as val2,
       (select top 1 t3.val3 from table3 t3 where b.time >= t3.time order by t3.time desc) as val3
from base b` with order by DESC and fixing the typo on the second table2 t3

Answer (score 2):

The general principle is to use outer joins to make sure you get results even if there are no matches in the second table. You can then use an inequality to restrict anything that goes over, and `max` to pick the highest of what's left.

This could be inefficient for large tables, as you're essentially doing a cross join of `t2` and `t3`. It may be better to do each a nested query and join the results afterwards:

```
-- Easier to read    
Select
  b.time,
  max(t2.val2) As val2,
  max(t3.val3) As val3
From
  base b
    left outer join
  table2 t2
    on b.time >= t2.time
    left outer join
  table3 t3
    on b.time >= t3.time
Group By
  b.time
Order By
  b.time;

-- Probably faster
Select
  n.time,
  n.val2,
  Max(t3.val3)
From (
    Select
      b.time,
      Max(t2.val2) As val2
    From
      base b
        left outer join
      table2 t2
         On b.time >= t2.time
    Group By
      b.time
    ) n
    Left Outer Join
  table3 t3
    On n.time >= t3.time
Group By
  n.time,
  n.val2
Order By
  n.time;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3545e/15

Comment: My original example tables were a bit misleading -- I have edited the SQL tables statement to make this more challenging.  Val2 and Val3 are not always increasing over time so MAX() used in this way doesn't capture what I'm after.  I don't want the MAX value of all following values.  Instead, I need the value from the value table that has the maximum table2.time <= base.time .